A question related to the AMS Author handbook
In the "AMS Author Handbook" it says

Do not use TeX coding to control line and page breaks. Lines and pages may break differently in the published article from the way they break in the file you submit. If you insert TeX coding for line and page breaks, it will have to be removed for production.

What does it mean that I can't use line and page breaks? Can I use \\ to break lines? How about \newline and \newpage commands?

An author should never use \\ or \newline in their text. Of course \\ is ok in alignments, tables, maybe even in \section{Foo \\ bar} but it has no place in the document it self. Mental image to remember: if you're using \\ or \newline in the text, then you are doing it wrong.

It means that you should not force line or page breaks, as  if you optimise the breaks for an A4 (or US letter) page size they will all be wrong when the document is formatted  for the journal at a custom page size, and it will cost extra time for AMS staff to find all the forced breaks and remove them.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for your reply! But what if I need to start a new page (maybe at the end of a section or something)? Is there a way to accomplish that without using \newpage?

The AMS editors will sort out page breaking.  If you are submitting to the AMS then just do what they ask. If you are not submitting to the AMS and you re making camera ready copy then of course these notes do not apply.

the issue is not using \newpage . the editors are not asking that you do not use that command, they are asking that you do not force page breaks. So " Is there a way to accomplish that without using \newpage?" is the wrong question to ask.
